# Ionic: Multiple Infinite Scrolls, one view

Tags: ionic-framework, dashboard, ionic5

I am trying to create a dashboard-like layout, displaying multiple lists in a singular view. I am trying to implement these lists with Ionic's Infinite Scroll component.

Ionic documentation specifies that it is best practice to have one Ion Content per view. Furthermore, each Infinite Scroll component should be linked to a singular Ion Content. So my question is: How would one achieve multiple Infinite Scroll components in a singular view, using something like the grid layout system?

Even though I was able to achieve using multiple Infinite Scrolls nested in multiple Ion Contents in a single view, I am concerned about this causing problems down the line, and it's already causing some unexpected behavior when scrolling.
I am trying to achieve something like this, with each of the visible lists employing an Infinite Scroll:

[Layout With Multiple Infinite Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6sq4.png)

Is there any good way to go about this? Or should I just stick to keeping Infinite Scrolls contained in separate views?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.